# Python imports in programmes installed via setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider a mock-up project with the following structure:

```
.
├── mod1
│   ├── good_day.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── say_hello.py
└── setup.py
```

`say_hello.py` contains a class with a method:

```
class SayHello():

    def sayIt(self):
        print("Hello World!")
```

`good_day.py` is a small programme that uses the `SayHello` class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from say_hello import SayHello

hello = SayHello()
hello.sayIt()

print("And have a good day!")
```

The programme does what it is expected to:

```
$ ./good_day.py 
Hello World!
And have a good day!
```

Now imagine this programme is to be distributed in a package, that is where `setup.py` comes in:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding=utf8

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "good-day",
    version = "0.1",
    packages = find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'good_day=mod1.good_day',
        ],
    },
)
```

But an exercise installing the programme in a virtual environment ends in tragedy:

```
$ python3 -m venv env

$ source env/bin/activate

(env) $ python3 setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing good_day.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to good_day.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to good_day.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing top-level names to good_day.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'good_day.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'good_day.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/mod1
copying mod1/say_hello.py -> build/lib/mod1
copying mod1/__init__.py -> build/lib/mod1
copying mod1/good_day.py -> build/lib/mod1
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mod1
copying build/lib/mod1/say_hello.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mod1
copying build/lib/mod1/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mod1
copying build/lib/mod1/good_day.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mod1
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mod1/say_hello.py to say_hello.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mod1/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mod1/good_day.py to good_day.cpython-38.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying good_day.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying good_day.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying good_day.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying good_day.egg-info/entry_points.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying good_day.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/good_day-0.1-py3.8.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing good_day-0.1-py3.8.egg
Removing /home/user/src/py-mods/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/good_day-0.1-py3.8.egg
Copying good_day-0.1-py3.8.egg to /home/user/src/py-mods/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages
good-day 0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing good_day script to /home/user/src/py-mods/env/bin

Installed /home/user/src/py-mods/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/good_day-0.1-py3.8.egg
Processing dependencies for good-day==0.1
Finished processing dependencies for good-day==0.1

$ good_day
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/src/py-mods/env/bin/good_day", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('good-day==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'good_day')()
  File "/home/user/src/py-mods/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/user/src/py-mods/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/user/src/py-mods/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/user/src/py-mods/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/user/src/py-mods/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/good_day-0.1-py3.8.egg/mod1/good_day.py", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'say_hello'
```

Essentially, once installed the programme can only find the `SayHello` class if the `import` instruction refers to the module explicitly:

```
from mod1.say_hello import SayHello
```

While this import fixes the programme installed via `setup` it breaks direct execution:

```
$ mod1/good_day.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mod1/good_day.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mod1.say_hello import SayHello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1'
```

What gives? Is there any formulation allowing for a successful import both for the installed programme and its direct execution?

**Update**: below are the results running the programme directly using the [suggestions by AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63831531/2066215). First with the full path in the import statement:

```
$ mod1/good_day.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mod1/good_day.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mod1.say_hello import SayHello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1'
```

And then using the [relative import path](https://github.com/akx/so63831434/blob/master/mod1/good_day.py):

```
$ mod1/good_day.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mod1/good_day.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .say_hello import SayHello
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring packages entirely with your import syntax, and running things with e.g. `python mod1/good_day.py` adds `mod1/` to `sys.path` first, which is why the absolute import works at all in the first place.

`mod1/good_day.py` should be e.g.

```py
from mod1.say_hello import SayHello
# or "from .say_hello import SayHello"

def main():
    hello = SayHello()
    hello.sayIt()
    print("And have a good day!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

after which you can run

```
python -m mod1.good_day
```

and things should work.

The entry point needs slight adjustment too (the added `main`):

```
        'console_scripts': [
            'good_day=mod1.good_day:main',
        ],
```

With this configuration, `good_day` should work when installed and using that entry point.

[You can find the documentation for `-m` ("run module") here.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)

Comment: This information is useful, but still I am unable to run the executable directly.

Comment: "Still unable" -- how? Do you get an error? What error?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Okay, I tried things out – the entry point was slightly wonky too. Edited the answer, and you can find working code at https://github.com/akx/so63831434

Comment: I updated the question with the results obtained with the formulations you suggested.